# Setting a custom value to the DeflateBufferSize results in 500 internal server error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, gzip, mod-deflate

I'm trying to reset the `DeflateBufferSize` directive like so in my .htaccess file:

`DeflateBufferSize 1024`
`SetOutputFilter DEFLATE`

But the result of each page is then 500 internal server error(this happens even if I set it to its default value of 8096). If I remove that line everything's fine. Why is this happening, do I need to set it differently?

Answer (score 1):

Please set it in `httpd.conf`. Things should work fine after that.

As you can learn from [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/), the [DeflateBufferSize](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_deflate.html#deflatebuffersize) directive can be set only at the server level and virtual host level (not at directory level, not in `.htaccess`). This is why Apache returns `500 Internal Server Error`.